# Using XPath to locate a node in a XML file with a HelpNDoc custom template

Tags: xml, pascal, helpndoc

I am trying to enhance my HTML template that is used with HelpNDoc. One thing I find lacking is the fact that the `meta description` tag is the same for all pages.

The template file is a mixture of pascal and HTML. At the moment this is the data in the template for showing the description tag:

```
<meta name="description" content="<% print(HndProjects.GetProjectSummary()); %>" />
```

I have created a mapping XML document which contains the needed descriptions. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<HelpTopics xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Topic>
        <Caption>Overview</Caption>
        <ID>msa-overview</ID>
        <ContextID>0</ContextID>
        <Description>An introduction to Meeting Schedule Assistant.</Description>
    </Topic>
    <Topic>
        <Caption>Quick Start - Getting Started</Caption>
        <ID>msa-quick-start</ID>
        <ContextID>1</ContextID>
        <Description>A quick start guide to get you up and running with Meeting Schedule Assistant.</Description>
    </Topic>
    <Topic>
        <Caption>Using Meeting Schedule Assistant</Caption>
        <ID>msa</ID>
        <ContextID>2</ContextID>
        <Description>An overview of the menus in Meeting Schedule Assistant.</Description>
    </Topic>
</HelpTopics>
```

Is it possible, using pascal inside this HelpnDoc script to read the XML file? On their site they provide the details about the [`HndProjects`](https://www.helpndoc.com/sites/default/files/documentation/html/HelpNDocAPImethods.html#HNDPROJECTS) and it mentions:

> `function GetProjectId: string;`
>
> Returns the currently open project id.

So I would basically like to get this value from the XML data file:

```
HelpTopics/Topic/ID[text()='<% HndProjects.GetProjectId(); %>'
```

But I don't know how to use such an XPath with a HelpNDoc Pascal script.

## Update

I tried adding this code to get be going:

```
function GetDescription(sTopicID: string): String;
var
    nodeTopic: TDOMNode;
    doc: TXMLDocument;
begin
    try
        // Read in the xml file
        ReadXMLFile(doc, '.\MSA-Help-Descriptions.xml');
        // Get the node
        //nodeTopic := doc.DocumentElement.FindNode(
        // How do we get the node at:  HelpTopics/Topic/ID[text()=sTopicID];
    finally
        doc.Free;
    end;
    GetDescription := 'xxxx';
end;
```

Then, inside HelpNDoc I tried to compile the script but I got these errors:

[image: Log]

So I am not sure if I can even do what I want, unless I have missed some steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this feed back from the software authors:

> Please know that HelpNDoc's scripting engine is only a subset of the pascal language and libraries. There are no XML libraries available in the scripting language.
>   It may be possible to use a third-party XML library but this is not something that we tested or support.
>
> We recommend that you work with simpler structures which can be easily parsed via simple code such as comma separated (CSV) files.

Therefore, I created a simple text file where each line represents a meta description and the line number matches the context id of the help topic.

Then I modified the pascal script that is used for compiling:

```
function ReadFile(helpContextID: integer): string;
var
    FText  : TStringList;
begin
    FText := TStringList.Create;
    try
       FText.LoadFromFile('D:\My Programs\2017\MeetSchedAssist\HelpNDoc\HelpTopicDescriptions.txt');
       result := FText[helpContextID];
    finally
       FText.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Finally, I made the following call to set the meta description:

```
<meta name="description" content="<% print(ReadFile(HndTopics.GetTopicHelpContext(HndGeneratorInfo.CurrentTopic))); %>" />
```

---

## Update

For what it is worth, I improved the code by making the `TStringList` a global variable. Then I read in the data file into this list only once and use that in the creation of the meta descriptions. Finally, I free the list towards the end of the building process in the script file.